# Asking the dates

Tags: sentence-construction

My boss told me to give him bank statement. I needed to ask dates of bank statements. Would it be correct if I say the sentences below to ask?

> 1) Between which dates you want bank statements to be?
>
> 2) Bank statements between which date do you want?

Comment: Your boss would understand you but it would not be correct. It's clumsy English. Prefer: **Can you tell me the dates of the bank statements you require, or the exact period concerned.**

Comment: Are both sentence grammatically wrong or odd?

Comment: (1) should be "... _do_ you want the...". In (2) the order of words is quite unnatural.

Comment: I know order of words of second sentences is very unnatural but I just wonder if it is grammatically correct ır not .